# What are these types of 当て字?

Tags: meaning, kanji, ateji

I was trying to find ways to translate people's names into 当て字, and came across [this website](http://isop.sub.jp/main3/isop_mobile/ateji/ateji.html) that seems to list 4 types of 当て字:
暴走族風【ぼうそうぞくふう】, 宝塚風【たからづかふう】, お子様風【おこさまふう】, 難読文字【なんどくもじ】
The best translation I can make is "Biker-style", "Takarazuka-style", "Childlike-style", and "Difficult Words". Are these 4 standard types of 当て字, or is it something the author of the website made up himself?

Comment: Is it you or the website who is reading 風 as かぜ?  Either way, it is weird.

Comment: In this context (meaning "style"), 風 is read ふう. Also 宝塚 is read たからづか.

Comment: Thanks, I made both of these changes, they were my own mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, that website is ***in no way*** an authoritative guide to [当]{あ}て[字]{じ}.  It even says 「当て字で[遊]{あそ}ぼう」("Let's play with ateji!") in a highlighted color.  The four ateji patterns given are completely random and just for fun.

All I want to do here is to explain the first two patterns as many Japanese-learners would be unfamiliar with the ideas behind them.  The other two, 「お[子様風]{こさまふう}」 and 「[難読文字風]{なんどくもじふう}」 could be figured out by using a dictionary.

1) [暴走族風]{ぼうそうぞくふう}

暴走族 (hot-rodders) are known for their love of kanji.  They write everything in kanji --- but only in abnormal kanji.  Below, they are saying 「よろしく！アイラブユー」 and that kanji version of 「よろしく」 is very famous among us non-暴走族 Japanese citizens as well.

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogimg.jp](http://livedoor.blogimg.jp/galud_school/imgs/c/b/cb6ff566.jpg))</sub>

2) [宝塚風]{たからづかふう}

宝塚 is a highly popular female-only theatrical company.  (It is almost impossible to get tickets for its shows!)

The actresses of Takarazuka, with basically no exceptions, have ***dramatic-sounding and gorgeous-looking*** stage names - both first and last names. Below are some examples.

[image]

Some of you might notice that the list contains masculine-sounding names.  That is because some actresses of Takarazuka always play the male parts.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a vague idea of what these kanji represented but you've helped clarify exactly what they meant.

Answer (score 2):

The website appears to be an 当て字 generator. You input kana and it outputs 当て字 based on the above-listed arbitrary styles. They aren't real types of 当て字.

As an aside, I'm not sure exactly what the criteria is for the first two (at a glance I'd say it could be kanji with bad connotations vs good/imperial connotations), but the latter two just create 当て字 using simple and complex kanji respectively.

Comment: The criteria are SO clear only if you are familiar with how 暴走族 like to write things and how 宝塚 actresses like to create their stage names.